# Spring Boot 3 with testing in Spock doesn't create context in @SpringBootTest test

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, spock

I created simple project with the newest Spring Boot 3 and spock versions, which you can find here: https://github.com/RafBorkowski/SpringBoot3SpockExample. When I try to start test with junit, context of spring starting normally and test passing, but when I try to do the same test in spock I noticed that spring is not starting and not creating context, what lead to test failure. When I downgrade Spring boot version to 2.7.5, everything work normally.

P.S. I added screenshots with responses in README on github.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you post what error messages you are seeing, or any more detail?

Comment: I have this information in spock:
```
Condition not satisfied:

testService != null
|           |
null        false

Condition not satisfied:

testService != null
|           |
null        false

 at com.example.testspring3.TestSpring3ApplicationSpec.context test(TestSpring3ApplicationSpec.groovy:15)
```
And in console I cannot see characteristic info about starting spring server in spock case.

Comment: That's helpful, it would be better to update/edit your answer with that info, so folks will see it easier and not have to comb through comments

Comment: I know, but I cannot paste any images to my post, so I added screenshots with responses in README on github

Comment: https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/1539

Comment: That is the answer for my question :D thanks a lot. Adding annotation @ContextConfiguration resolve problem and I hope that this bug will be fixed very soon

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting NullPointerException on autowired test subject in Spock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75490552/getting-nullpointerexception-on-autowired-test-subject-in-spock)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update to Spock 2.4-M1 which was released today.