# Getting NullPointerException on autowired test subject in Spock

Tags: java, spring, spock

I have a simple Spock specification annotated with `@SpringBootTest` and the class under test annotated with `@Autowired`, but the test subject is null in the unit test. The controller is annotated with the `@Controller` stereotype. Here's the test:

```
@SpringBootTest
class BeerControllerTest extends Specification {
    @Autowired
    BeerController testSubject

    def "get beer by ID"() {
        when:
        def result = testSubject.getBeerById(UUID.randomUUID())

        then:
        result
        println result
    }
}
```

I have `spock-core` and `spock-spring` on the classpath (full code is [here](https://github.com/spartanhooah/spring-6-web-mvc)). In fact, the Spring Context is not even coming up when this test is run, which I have never seen in ~2 years of using Spock and Spring Boot. What am I missing here? It seems like a pretty simple use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update to Spock to 2.4-M1 as it fixes a problem with Spring Boot 3 / Spring 6.

See [Spring Boot 3 with testing in Spock doesn't create context in @SpringBootTest test](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74633439/2145769)

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it! I wish I'd noticed the "no Spring context" part earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your `getBeerById` method not mapped to a URL endpoint using @RequestMapping or similar, I think that it should be:

```
    @RequestMapping("/api/v1/beer/{id}")
    public Beer getBeerById(@PathVariable UUID id) {
        return beerService.getBeerById(id);
    }
```

Comment: I have since added that annotation, but still the same result. But, since I'm calling the controller method directly (rather than using MockMvc), that shouldn't matter, right? And the larger problem is that the Spring Context is not coming up at all. I think if I fix that it'll fix the NPE.